# RubyOnRails sending params with form_remote_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, routes

I know some will think that i should use form_tag with :remote=>true, but i don't know how to render an entire html output....

My problem is the following:

I have this form that sends a collection through 3 comboxes

```
<%= form_remote_tag :url => report_client_reports_path, :update => :graphic do%>
<%#= form_tag reporte_client_reports_path%>
 <p><%= label_tag :supermercados %>
 <%=select_tag "supermercados[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@supermercados, "id", "name"),{:multiple=>true, :id => "supermarkets"}%>
 </p>

  <p><%= label_tag :cortes %>
<%=select_tag "cortes[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@cortes, "corte_real","cuts"),{:multiple=>true, :id => "cortes"}%>
 </p>

 <p><%= label_tag :productos %>
 <%= select_tag "productos[]", options_from_collection_for_select(@productos, "id", "name"),{:multiple=>true, :id => "products"}%>
</p>


<p><%= submit_tag 'Send' %></p>
<%end%>
```

If i uncommented this line:
    <%#= form_tag reporte_client_reports_path%>
It work good and present me the graph, but not the way i expect to work.

I have detected that using form_remote_tag, it sends all vars with their values, bu i dont know why my controller only see one value of each variable.

here is the controller:

```
  @super = params[:supermarkets]
  @superm = []
  @super.each do |s|
    @superm << Company.find(s).abbr
  end

  @cuts = params[:cuts]
  @prods = params[:products]
  @cortesGraph = []

  @cortess.to_a.each do |c|
   @cortesGraph  << "#{RawData.find_by_real_cut(c).cuts}"
  end
```

The objects @superm,@cuts and @products arent receving more than 1 value in the array, is a routing problem or a option i have missed in the form_remote_tag?

---

And update to simplyfy, what actually is still happening is this:

This Works:

```
<%= form_tag reporte_client_reports_path do%>
```

This doesn't:

```
<%= form_tag reporte_client_reports_path,:remote=>true do%>
```

The problem is that :remote is not sending my params as array it send all data as 1 var :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in functional way, but there might be something very weird with this in my controller:

```
 if request.xhr?
    @super = params[:supermercados].to_s.split(",")
    @cortess = params[:cortes].to_s.split(",")
    @prods = params[:productos].to_s.split(",")
end
```